# Google OAuth 2.0 inconsistent token type?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, access-token

Google says in its own [OAuth 2.0 specs](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#callinganapi) in accordance with the [OAuth 2.0 draft](http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer.html#authz-header) that the **authorization header** should be:

```
Authorization: Bearer {access_token}
```

And indeed it works with the **G+ API**.

But with the **Google Calendar API** you need to change the `Bearer` to `OAuth`!

```
Authorization: OAuth {access_token}
```

You can try it yourself in the [Google OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/).

I have discovered this after I hit my head several times against the keyboard.

I couldn't find anything about `OAuth` token type anywhere.
Is this an example of Google's ignorance of its own guidelines and standards, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

The "Authorization: OAuth" format is supported for legacy reasons, earlier drafts of OAuth 2 used this schema.

In your code you should use "Authorization: Bearer". If this is not working then let me know exactly what API (exact URL and parameters) you are trying to use.

As an example, the following works with both Bearer and OAuth:
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer XXX" 
"https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList"

Comment: It didn't work with this one `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList`.
I have  tried it again and it now works with `Bearer XXX`.
But I'm absolutely sure that it was not my mistake because,
I tried two URLs with the same setup: `https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/playlists?alt=json`
and the former. And whilst the **youtube URL** worked with `Bearer XXX`, the **calendar URL** didn't.
When I changed the header to `OAuth XXX` both worked. I called both as you see them plus the `Authorization: Bearer XXX` header.