# Setup push notifications for Google Calendar API using PHP client

Tags: push-notification, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I want to setup ***[push notifications for Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push)*** where my server is notified whenever a particular resource on Google calendar api changes. I want to do this using the ***[Google APIs client library for PHP](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/)***.

But it seems ***[they don't have a method](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/issues/detail?id=393)*** for watching google calendar resources in PHP library. May be other libraries have a `watch` method, but I'm not too sure about that.

Basically to setup push notifications for a particular resource you have to send a post request to a URL like this...

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/my_calendar@gmail.com/events/watch
Authorization: Bearer auth_token_for_current_user
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "id": "01234567-89ab-cdef-0123456789ab", // Your channel ID.
  "type": "web_hook",
  "address": "https://mydomain.com/notifications" // Your receiving URL.
}
```

I can do that easily using curl in PHP, but my problem is that request isn't authorized with a Google OAuth token, so it results in an error.

I want to know if there is a workaround to this problem....

**UPDATE**

I was trying to send the connect to Google without adding proper headers so I was getting an authorization error. Having corrected that part, I am still having trouble with an `Invalid Credentials` error. Here's what my snippet looks like...

```
    $url = sprintf("https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/%s/events/watch", $calendar);

    /* setup the POST parameters */
    $fields = array(
        'id'        => "some_unique_key",
        'type'      => "web_hook",
        'address'   => sprintf("http://%s//event_status/update_google_events", $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])
        );

    /* convert the POST parameters to URL query */
    $fields_string = '';
    foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
        $fields_string .= sprintf("%s=%s&", $key, $value);
    }
    rtrim($fields_string, '&');

    /* setup POST headers */
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    $headers[] = 'Authorization: OAuth ' . $access_token;

    /* send POST request */
    $channel = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
    $response = curl_exec($channel);
    curl_close($channel);

    error_log($response);
```

Comment: Any idea what I'm doing wrong here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34654504/calendar-events-notification-not-received-on-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my solution to the problem. I figured out what I was doing wrong by fiddling around a bit in [Google playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/).

What I did was that

- I JSON-encoded the body of POST request instead of sending a URL query parameters.
- Changed the `Authorization` part of POST request [from `OAUth {access_token}` to `Bearer {access_token}`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16066709/206613).

Basically just followed the [Google's documentation for setting up push notifications](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push#watch).

```
$url = sprintf("https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/%s/events/watch", $calendar);

/* setup the POST parameters */
$fields = json_encode(array(
    'id'        => "some_unique_key",
    'type'      => "web_hook",
    'address'   => sprintf("http://%s//event_status/update_google_events", $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])
    ));

/* setup POST headers */
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token;

/* send POST request */
$channel = curl_init();
curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
$response = curl_exec($channel);
curl_close($channel);

error_log($response);
```

Comment: Thanks for that, How did you go about receiving the notifications for changes? I am trying to use get_headers() but whenever i change anything in my calendar I don't get notified at the URL provided. How can I know that I have received a notification?

Comment: You may want to use apache_request_headers() @kakashihatake2

Comment: @Chandrew ok, but Google is not calling back that page only

Comment: Then you may need to issue an actual watch request. I'd recommend logging any POST request coming in at your watch notifications URL.

Comment: @vikkun Any idea how to receive push notification on remote php script? What should I put into the script to receive & intercept message properly? I tried with `getallheaders()`. But its empty.

Comment: @kakashihatake2 FYI, make sure your site has a valid SSL certificate, or you will not get any notifications at all.

Comment: @SamuelKilada Thanks for the reply. Yes, I figured that out later on... Everything works okay now... :)

Answer (score 4):

I managed to do it via the php client library :

```
$channel = new Google_Service_Calendar_Channel($client);
$channel->setId('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001');
$channel->setType('web_hook');
$channel->setAddress('https://www.yourserver.com/handleWatch.php');
$watchEvent = $service->events->watch(yourCalendarId, $channel, array());
```

BR

Comment: Which service is the variable $service ?

Comment: @Berni `\Google\Service\Calendar\Calendar` service